# Web-based CTI Adapter issues with Canvas and VisualForce [Now Resolved]

Tags: visualforce, canvas, opencti

**[FYI : The below issue has now been resolved as of Summer 14]**

I am integrating a web-based CTI Adapter into SF using Canvas and the Open CTI API.

**Background:**

1. The Canvas App contains the end point to the web-based CTI Adapter
   (currently on Heroku).
2. The Canvas App is included in the Call Center by adding it to the Definition File
3. The Call Center allows the web-based CTI Adapter to be exposed to SF via the left-hand sidebar.
4. All standard stuff following these docs : http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_cti/index.htm

**Issue**

1. The Canvas App displays fine when navigating standard SF pages (list views, page layouts etc..)
2. The Canvas App throws the following error if the user navigates to a VF page:

> Oops, there was an error rendering Force.com Canvas application
>   [App_1]. Your browsing session has ended or is invalid. Please
>   re-login to Salesforce.com again.

Has anyone else experienced this? There is no mention in the docs that this should be an issue.

**Does anyone know of a fix/workaround?**

Comment: Was this ever resolved? I'm curious about this.

Comment: Hi Artie, this issue has now been resolved as of Summer 14.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like there is an issue with the Visualforce session being generated.

Can you open a support case and provide login access to salesforce support and steps to reproduce if possible?  Then email jhurst[at]salesforce.com with the case number and I can take a look.

Thanks

Comment: Thank you Jay for getting in touch. Email is on its way.